# What are HBAKED and HBAKED... files?

Tags: file-types, filetype

Whenever I notice my storage go down, I use WinDirStat to see what is taking up space. I have noticed that the WinSxS folder always takes up a lot of space. I looked deeper into the folder and saw a bunch of .HBAKED files and .HBAKED(with random suffixes) files.
Examples: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DCGrxNJxzoRUWuMZtyNc8CQ7BCepTiPa?usp=sharing (I can't provide images cause of my reputation)

Example path `"C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsappscene_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_192f5ff060b7ee8a\360.png.hBaked"`

Does anybody know what these are? I am using a PC with Windows 10, and a AMD gpu and cpu. Also, can I delete them? Finally, where did they come from?

I also saw this: https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/kum7aw/hbaked_and_hbakedproj_help_on_a_friends_computer/ so it seems other people have it.

**Edit:** This seems to be an AMD problem, as they are all in folders that have AMD in them. It also seems to be related to 3D models somehow, as I've seen .glb files (which Windows Explorer says are 3D models) and .png files that seem to be pictures of them.

This is really weird as I have never seen those 3D models or images ever before.

**Edit #2:** Link to zipped version of one of the folders: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AN7nrO4yssaqJp-BgdtOztczR_IQY6oi/view?usp=sharing

Paths to folders:

```
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp-bare-scene_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_92b14febcfa056cd, Size: 8683035.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp-missioncontrol-scene_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_7d3c087b1fdf6506, Size: 425039497.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp-preplacementconfig_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_a64fd3adb9fd8776, Size: 21304.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp-scene_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_192f5ff060b7ee8a, Size: 845797538.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp.appxmain.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_de-de_6cf31c8decef0f41, Size: 2208.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp.appxmain.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_en-gb_0e5b3768e0a46741, Size: 2200.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp.appxmain.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_en-us_15e3f286dbcd1b06, Size: 2200.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp.appxmain.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_es-es_15af4f6adbf40cab, Size: 2232.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp.appxmain.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_es-mx_17e63d10da87f056, Size: 2232.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp.appxmain.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_fr-ca_b0dd0fb3d39e8933, Size: 2232.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp.appxmain.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_fr-fr_b866c569cec6230d, Size: 2232.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp.appxmain.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_it-it_a28ebbb0a5f8088b, Size: 2200.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp.appxmain.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_ja-jp_44b43abd99131a66, Size: 2208.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp.appxmain.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_ko-kr_e81e17728b83e17c, Size: 2200.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp.appxmain.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_nl-nl_ceefe3e564d5170d, Size: 2208.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp.appxmain.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_ru-ru_5f050a3b2cd216ad, Size: 2232.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp.appxmain.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_zh-cn_756a5cf4c2eef518, Size: 2192.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp.appxmain.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_zh-tw_79669a4ac05fd188, Size: 2200.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp.appxmain_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.746_none_6b266903a2fec967, Size: 1611628.
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_environmentsapp.appxsetup_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.423_none_b9fc9439ddf30c73, Size: 17426.
Total Size: 1281201404.
```

Sizes are in bytes, because I used a C# program to get them.

Comment: Have you ever run Disk Cleanup, and select windows updates as part if the cleanup? This can remove gigs of old files from the Winxsx folder.

Comment: You shouldn’t be touching WinSxS, the contents of that folder, exist for a reason that might not always be apparent

Comment: @Moab Yes I use disk cleanup but it never removes those files

Comment: @Ramhound I have never touched the files myself, I use Disk Cleanup and the other windows processes to remove them. They never delete the HBAKED files though. I also only ever view them, whenever I want to delete them, I use Disk Cleanup (as said above)

Comment: I look at WinSxS on 3 Windows 10 machines. Under 10GB on all 3. I run Disk Cleanup, all items, cleanup system files weekly.  I do not have the folders you mention. If you believe the files can be deleted without harm, try a new temporary Admin user, log in to that new user and see if you can delete the files. Also try Safe Mode to delete the files. If they are small, it may not be worth doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have several such files on my computer with very suggestive names. Here is an example:

[image]

So let's do some sleuthing.

By their sub-folder names, these seem to be animation files in binary
(non-textual) format.

An examination of the contained printable strings in the files shows strings such
as `char*`, which points to them probably being written in one of C/C++/C#.

The string "hBaked" itself is very suggestive of "half baked".

"Baking" is a term used in animation. In the post from
Blender Stack Exchange
[What does “Baking” mean?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14416/what-does-baking-mean),
it is said:

> The purpose of baking is to save in render times, because Blender recalculates all shadows, lighting and what not, every single frame, which results in a lot of time wasted time for long animations.
>
> Baking can also mean precalculating physics simulations such as Cloth or Rigid Body. For this Blender saves them to a file, which then loads when rendering or playing back the animation so that the physics don't have to be recalculated every time.

Half-baked would in that case mean pre-processed animations that are still somewhat
modifiable or that can be incorporated in larger animated scenes as textures or
objects.

These files are owned by `TrustedInstaller`, which means that they belong to some
installed application and were installed by the Windows Installer.

The folder `C:\Windows\WinSxS` itself is Microsoft's answer to
[DLL Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell),
where `SxS` stands for
[Side-by-side assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly),
guarding the DLL context of most installed applications.
Multiple installed versions of the same application, will create multiple entries
in `WinSxS`, all separated.

In short, these files belong to installed applications.
Deleting them will requires drastic measures because their owner is the
Windows super-privileged pseudo-account `TrustedInstaller` (not recommended),
but will also cause some installed application to malfunction.

If there are too many of them, you may guess what application has installed them
by the sub-folder names. We know that this is an application that uses video sequences,
perhaps a game, but you cannot delete these files without also uninstalling the game.

Unless these files take up an appreciable part of WinSxS,
I would suggest to leave them be.
If Disk Cleanup does not delete them, this means that they are still used
by some installed application.

---

In your files I have found these XML text snippets:

```
"generator":"Khronos Blender glTF 2.0 I/O","version":"2.0"
"generator":"Microsoft GLTF Exporter 2.2.3.0-b82-gf0447d2"
```

This, combined with the fact that you have lots of `.glb` files,
validate my assumption of these being video files,
where some are created by Blender.

These files belong to an application written within the framework of
[Windows Mixed Reality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mixed_Reality):

> Windows Mixed Reality is a mixed reality platform introduced as part of the Windows 10 operating system, which provides augmented reality and mixed reality experiences with compatible head-mounted displays.
> ...
> The platform is also used for virtual reality headsets designed for use on the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, which are built to specifications implemented as part of Windows Mixed Reality, but lack support for augmented-reality experiences.

Microsoft HoloLens is the flagship device in Windows Mixed Reality.

One of your files is named `HoloTour.glb`, so it might be that you have
installed the
[Microsoft HoloLens - HoloTour](http://www.jiarenhui.com/hololens-holo-tour),
described as
"an immersive 360 degree virtual travel experience with holographic scenery and spacial sounds".

Another file is `HaloRecruit.glb`, which might mean that that you
have installed the game
[Halo Recruit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/halo-recruit/9p1vd7tn2frg)
from the Microsoft Store.

Final answer: These are applications written for Windows Mixed Reality.
It seems like you are experimenting with Microsoft HoloLens
augmented reality.

Windows Mixed Reality itself is a part of Windows and shouldn't be
uninstalled (I don't even know if this is possible or if that will also
remove these files, since they belong to their applications).
The applications themselves can be uninstalled, each according to
how they were installed in the first place.

Comment: Could Blender possibly make these?

Comment: It's possible, but I haven't found any hint for the origin of the files, at least those on my computer.

Comment: thank you for answering, this answers two of my questions, if you can find out where they come from, I would accept and award you the bounty. Thanks!

Comment: If you could post some of your files online with their full paths, I'll look into it.

Comment: do you mean the files and folders themselves, or just their paths?

Comment: I mean a zipped example of the files, and a list (textual) of full folders, and I'll see what I can guess.

Comment: Thanks for the files, I think I have the final answer now.

Answer (score 2):

They are for the Windows Mixed Reality app.
The folder name gave it away. The "amd64" part of the folder name just means x64 files, but the "environmentsapp" part is the program or framework they belong to, which if you google it, it comes up "Windows Mixed Reality".

I did some research on "Windows Mixed Reality hbaked" and found a download page on Microsoft's site for a Windows Mixed Reality asset update.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/asset-update-for-windows-10-version-2004-mixed-reality-october-1-2020-c54176e8-59e5-26cb-1172-7a632bebb06d

These files are a part of the asset pack that ships with the Microsoft Mixed Reality app. If you don't use this app and want to free up space, the proper way would be to uninstall the app. In Apps & Features, the app is named "Mixed Reality Portal" not "Windows Mixed Reality".

Comment: I won't award the bounty yet, but this is a really good answer